# Find linkedin profile, using linkedin api with nodejs

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I am trying to figure out how to use linkedin api for the current scenario:
-I have a list of company domains and I want to check if a profile with this domain name exists in linkedin.

I have completed the steps for generating: access and refresh tokens,but I am struggling finding the api call where I can use this domain name to check if profile exists.
Is there any resource/documentation ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see all Organization Endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).